# Criar links com tags cadastradas no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um campo no `MySQL` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
Alesso; Anitta; Billboard; Marshmello; Poo Bear
```

Preciso pegar cada um dos valores em separados e criar um link assim:

```
<a href="#">Alesso</a>
```

Não consigo ler individualmente cada valor.

Comment: Em qual linguagem voce quer fazer?

Comment: usando PHP + MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa quebrar a `string` em uma `array`, use o método explode do `PHP`: [Explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php):

```
$arr = 'Alesso; Anitta; Billboard; Marshmello; Poo Bear';
$EXP = explode(';', $arr);
foreach($EXP as $link)
{
      echo '<a href="#">'.$link.'</a>'.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Se o padrão é `"; "`, não deveria no `explode()` conter o espaço após o ponto e vírgula? No HTML tá retornando um espaço, muito embora o HTML ignore esse espaço.

Comment: Acho que no geral não faz diferença, a não ser que queira quebrar com 100% de precisão

Comment: nessa caso é melhor fazer apenas por `;` e utilizar a função `trim` na variavel `$link`

Answer (score 1):

Se esse campo estará sempre neste padrão, você consegue fazer no mysql com CONCAT e REPLACE, ex:

```
SELECT
    -- Aqui você substitui o x.nomes pela sua tabela.campo
    CONCAT('<a href="#">' , REPLACE(x.nomes, '; ', '</a><a href="#">') , '</a>') AS links
FROM
    -- Aqui você substitui pela sua tabela
    (SELECT 'Alesso; Anitta; Billboard; Marshmello; Poo Bear' AS nomes) AS x;
```

Answer (score 1):

[exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/VovUvq)

```
$str = 'Alesso; Anitta; Billboard; Marshmello; Poo Bear';
//para evitar de retirar espaços em nomes compostos
$output  = str_replace("; ", ";", $str);
$result = explode(';', $output);
foreach($result as $link)
{
  echo "<a href='#'>".$link."</a>\n";
}
```

- [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) - substitui todas as ocorrências da string de procura com a string de substituição
- [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) - divide uma string principal em partes menores com base em um caractere divisor

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma é utilizando um sistema de repetição

```
$sql = "select coluna from tabela";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

while($dados = mysqli_fecth_array($result)) {
 echo "<a href=".base64_encode($dados['coluna']).".php>".$dados['coluna']."</a>";
}
```

Vale lembrar que foi criado um link criptografado em base64. A vantagem se dá quando houver espaços " ", caracter este não aceito como url pelo apache, são criptografados.

Para descriptografar use

```
base64_decode($string);
```